# PowerPoint Add-In re-appears

Tags: c#, powerpoint

I created a custom pane add-in for Powerpoint in the first project. Now I created the second project which has no thing related to the first project, but when I run the second project, the custom pane in the first project still appears. Why is that?

Sorry, but I am a newbie in Powerpoint Add-in programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Power Point Orb >> Power Point Options >> Add-ins >> COM Add-ins >> [Go..] 

Select and Remove the old project from the list and click [OK].
```